# dev/sda2 error in every boot

Tags: error-handling

I had windows 10 installed on my 4 year old Lenovo G50-70 laptop. I erased my disk and installed ubuntu 18.04, and it was running fine. But every time I booted up the system started showing dev/sda2 error and I/O error, and had to run fsck to repair the drive. The same problem persisted with installations of Linux Mint and Elementary OS. But Windows 10 never had any problems before; and is running without any errors now that I have reinstalled it. What could be the issue? Is there any problem with the hard disk?

Comment: Open the `Disks` app, select the disk in the left pane, click on the "hamburger" icon, select `SMART Data & Tests`. Edit your question and show me screenshots of the Data window, and I'll take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft likes to hide errors like these. You will need to open the log files and look for it yourself.

In linux you get the error shown but can ignore it -short- term.

> Is there any problem with the hard disk?

Likely. Otherwise a filesystem check would fix it.

> What could be the issue?

Probably [badblocks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/badblocks.8.html).  See [How to read the current bad blocks list for the disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857936/how-to-read-the-current-bad-blocks-list-for-the-disk) or [How can I know the number of bad sectors on my hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104063/how-can-i-know-the-number-of-bad-sectors-on-my-hard-drive)

If those badblocks keep increasing... replace the disk